# IE8 returns "Cannot find 'javascript:...." when calling javascript programmatically from c++ code

Tags: javascript, c++, internet-explorer-8

I have a program that works well on IE6, and now on IE8 it doesn´t!

i´m using "IWebBrowser2:navigate2" to execute a javascript function that´s on a webpage

```
<script language="javascript">
function LocalSubmit(i) {document.form1.MediaCode.value=i; document.form1.submit();}
</script>
```

EX: javascript:LocalSubmit("555");

I get: "Windows Internet Explorer" error message saying "Cannot find 'javascript:LocalSubmit('555')'. Make sure the path or Internet address is correct.

[image]

So, i would like to know how DO i do it correctly? i.e put said javascript: lines as the "url" to navigate the IWebBrowser2 control to.

```
void CHtmlCtrl::Navigate(LPCTSTR lpszURL, DWORD dwFlags /* = 0 */,
LPCTSTR lpszTargetFrameName /* = NULL */ ,
LPCTSTR lpszHeaders /* = NULL */, LPVOID lpvPostData /* = NULL */,
DWORD dwPostDataLen /* = 0 */)
{   
CString strURL(lpszURL);

COleSafeArray vPostData;
if (lpvPostData != NULL)
{
   if (dwPostDataLen == 0)
      dwPostDataLen = lstrlen((LPCTSTR) lpvPostData);

   vPostData.CreateOneDim(VT_UI1, dwPostDataLen, lpvPostData);
}
HRESULT res;


res = m_pBrowserApp->Navigate2(COleVariant(strURL, VT_BSTR), COleVariant((long)   dwFlags, VT_I4), COleVariant(lpszTargetFrameName, VT_BSTR), 
                        vPostData, COleVariant(lpszHeaders, VT_BSTR));
```

Tks!

Comment: I feel like I'm on the Wayback Machine

Comment: typo: `LocalSubmitt` vs `LocalSubmit` -- Is this typo in your real code?

Comment: just corrected my question, and whats is in my code is LocalSubmit tks